# Kafka Streams: reprocessing old data when windowing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Having a Kafka Streams application, that performs windowing(using original event time, not wallclock time) via Stream joins of e.g. 1 day.

If bringing up this topology, and reprocessing the data from the start (as in a lambda-style architecture), will this window keep that old data there? da
For example: if today is 2022-01-09, and I'm receiving data from 2021-03-01, will this old data enter the table, or will it be rejected from the start?

In that case - what strategies can be done to reprocess this data?

*UPDATE* Using Kafka Streams 2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer to OP Kafka Streams version 2.5:

When using event time, Kafka Streams will behave independent of the wallclock time, as long as no events contain the wallclock time. You should not have configured a `WallclockTimestampExtractor` as your timestamp extractor.

Kafka Streams will assign you input topic partitions to stream tasks, that will consume the partitions one event at a time. On any given topic, at most one partition will be assigned to a stream task. Time-windowed aggregations are carried out for each stream task separately. Kafka Streams uses an internal timestamp called "observedStreamTime" for each aggregation to keep track of the maximum timestamp seen so far. Incoming records are checked for their timestamp in comparison to the observedStreamTime. If they are older than the retention + grace period of the configured time window store, they will be dropped. Otherwise, they will be aggregated according to the configuration. The implementation can be found at https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/d5b53ad132d1c1bfcd563ce5015884b6da831777/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamWindowAggregate.java#L108-L175

This processing will always yield the same result, if the Kafka Streams application is reset. It is independent on the execution time of the processing. If events are dropped, the corresponding metrics are changed.

There is one caveat with this approach, when multiple topics are consumed. The observedStreamTime will reflect the highest timestamp of all partitions read by the stream task. If you have two topics (maybe because you want to join them) and one contains considerably younger data than the other (maybe because the latter received no new data), the observedStreamTime will be dominated by the younger topic. Events of the older topic might be dropped, if the time window configuration does not have enough retention or grace periods. See the JavaDoc of TimeWindows on the configuration options: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/d5b53ad132d1c1bfcd563ce5015884b6da831777/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindows.java

In your example the old data will be accepted, as long as the stream time has not progress too far. Reprocessing the whole data set should work, since it will linearly progress through your topic. If the old data is aggregated in a time-window with exceeding the window size + grace period, Kafka Streams will reject the record. In that case Kafka Streams will also issue an error message and adjust its metrics accordingly. So this behaviour should be easy to pick up.

I suggest to try out this reprocessing if feasible and watch the logs and metrics.

Comment: I adjusted the answer to Kafka Streams 2.5, which has no global stream time. There the situation allows for much less side-effects.